# WinBugs if else using step function

Tags: if-statement, winbugs

I want to construct a model like

```
Model3 <- function() {
  # Likelihood of the model  
  for (i in 1:n) {
    response2[i] ~ dbern(p[i])
    logit(p[i]) <- m[i]
    m[i] <- mfe[i]
    mfe[i] <- beta[1] + f[i]  

    # the f functions or the if-else step like
    f_branch[i, 2]  <- alpha 
    f_branch[i, 1]  <- 1+alpha*exp(-((1/phi)*X2[i,1])^2) 

    # the decision
    if_branch[i] <- 1 + step(-(X2[i,1] - 2)) 
    f[i] <- f_branch[i, if_branch[i]]
    f[i] <- f_branch[i, if_branch[i]]
  }

  # Prediction step
  for(ii in 1:ndist) {  
    if_branch2[ii] <- 1 + step(-(Dist[ii] - 2))     
    fhat[ii] <- f_branch2[ii, if_branch2[ii]]    
    fhat[ii] <- f_branch2[ii, if_branch2[ii]]     
    f_branch2[ii, 2] <- alpha 
    f_branch2[ii, 1] <- 1 + alpha*exp(-((1/phi)*Dist[ii])^2)
  }

  # Prior distribution of the fixed effects parameters
  beta[1] ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-6)}

  # priors for the f function
  alpha ~ dgamma(1, 1)
  phi ~ dunif(0, 2)
}
```

And I am getting an error: `Attempt to redefine node f[1]`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the error message is pretty self-explanatory - you define `f[1]`, and then define it again on the following line, since you have repeated the line:

```
f[i] <- f_branch[i, if_branch[i]]
```

Remove the second instance of that line, and that error should disappear.

You have also duplicated the line:

```
fhat[ii] <- f_branch2[ii, if_branch2[ii]]
```

so you'll need to remove the second instance of that as well.